# Use excel functions on a variable

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I'm trying to get the right most letter from a variable I have set and then assign either Male or Female to the result. Below is a snippet of the code I've tried.

```
Set Gender = rFirst.Offset(1, 5)

Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("E1").Value = "=if(right(" & Gender & ",1)=""M"",""Male"",if(right(" & Gender & ",1)=""F"",""Female"",""""))"
```

This is resulting in #NAME? being displayed.

Comment: You are putting the value of `Gender` into your formula, as a cursory examination of the formula will tell you, which the sheet will not understand. You need to use the address property to return the cell reference.

Comment: From your use of set, i'm assuming you're doing this in VBA, why not just use an IF ELSE IF statement to set the value?

Comment: in the formula, change `Gender` to `Gender.address` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks SJR, I have done that by adding .Address after Gender but now it's returning a blank cell

Comment: That means the last character is neither "M" nor "F".

Comment: I have changed the function to trim to see if it is pulling through the data `"=trim(" & Gender.Address & ")" ` but this is also returning a blank cell. However when I use just `Gender` it returns the un-formatted data

Comment: However after using the following `MsgBox Gender.Address` it does bring back the correct cell

Comment: What is in the cell? Perhaps you have some hidden characters.

Comment: I have found the issue, as the variable is being set from another sheet, the .address however is pulling the data from the same sheet where the formula is located.

Comment: So you'll need to add the sheet name into your formula string.

Comment: Thanks SJR, I've got it working now

Comment: I've added an answer below as getting rather wordy down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend as below

```
Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("E1").Value = "=if(right(EmployeeAll!" & gender.Address & ",1)=""M"",""Male"",if(right(EmployeeAll!" & gender.Address & ",1)=""F"",""Female"",""""))"
```

Comment: Thanks SJR, this worked perfectly. Thanks everyone else for input

Answer (score 1):

Your approach involves creating a worksheet equation and then using `Evaluate()` to calculate it.  Here is an alternative approach:

```
Sub jufg()
    Dim Gender As Range, sexCode As String
    Dim rFirst As Range
    Set rFirst = Range("A1")

    Set Gender = rFirst.Offset(1, 5)
    sexCode = Right(Gender.Value, 1)

    With Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("E1")
        If sexCode = "M" Then
            .Value = "Male"
        ElseIf sexCode = "F" Then
            .Value = "Female"
        Else
            .Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```